# Does Microsoft have a definitive list of URLs that are associated with OneDrive that we should allow through our proxies?

Tags: proxy, whitelist, onedrive

Does Microsoft have a definitive list of URLs that are associated with OneDrive that we should allow through our proxies?

We are trying to allow use of OneDrive personal in Windows 8.1 and higher, but our Bluecoat proxies have rules that block it.  We need to know all the URLs to open on our proxies to allow OneDrive personal to work in Windows 8.1 and higher.

Based on our own troubleshooting and the following links from Bluecoat, we've already identified the list following the URLs.

http://bluecoat.force.com/knowledgebase/articles/Solution/HowdoIallowSkydrivewhenblockingDenyingFileStorageSharingcategory

http://bluecoat.force.com/knowledgebase/articles/Solution/MicrosoftOneNoteisnotsynchronizingonSkyDrive

```
 *.lync.com
 *.microsoftonline.com
 *.microsoftonline-p.com
 *.outlook.com
 *.office365.com
 onmicrosoft.com
 skydrive.com
 *.live.com
 *.live.net
 *.gfx.ms
 *.sfx.ms
 *.demdex.net
 *.omtrdc.net
 *.microsoft.com
 *.livefilestore.com
```

Comment: Do you require full access to the website, or are you just wanting the ability for Windows 8.1 sync your OneDrive files?

Answer (score 2):

Today I came across an MS article titled "Required URLs and ports for OneDrive". The date on the article is 04/03/2018. Link to the source https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/required-urls-and-ports.

In summary, it says:

To use OneDrive, the following endpoints need to be accessible to client computers.

Destination hosts:

`onedrive.com`
`*.onedrive.com`
`onedrive.live.com`
`login.live.com`
`spoprod-a.akamaihd.net`
`*.mesh.com`
`p.sfx.ms`
`*.microsoft.com`
`fabric.io`
`*.crashlytics.com`
`vortex.data.microsoft.com`
`posarprodcssservice.accesscontrol.windows.net`
`redemptionservices.accesscontrol.windows.net`
`token.cp.microsoft.com`
`tokensit.cp.microsoft-tst.com`
`*.office.com`
`*.officeapps.live.com`
`*.aria.microsoft.com`
`*.mobileengagement.windows.net`
`*.branch.io`
`*.adjust.com`
`*.servicebus.windows.net`
`vas.samsungapps.com`
`odc.officeapps.live.com`
`login.windows.net`
`login.microsoftonline.com`
`*.files.1drv.com`
`*.onedrive.live.com`
`*.*.onedrive.live.com`
`storage.live.com`
`*.storage.live.com`
`*.*.storage.live.com`
`*.groups.office.live.com`
`*.groups.photos.live.com`
`*.groups.skydrive.live.com`
`favorites.live.com`
`oauth.live.com`
`photos.live.com`
`skydrive.live.com`
`api.live.net`
`apis.live.net`
`docs.live.net`
`*.docs.live.net`
`policies.live.net`
`*.policies.live.net`
`settings.live.net`
`*.settings.live.net`
`skyapi.live.net`
`snapi.live.net`
`*.livefilestore.com`
`*.*.livefilestore.com`
`storage.msn.com`
`*.storage.msn.com`
`*.*.storage.msn.com`

Destination ports: TCP 80, TCP 443

Comment: If I add http://*live*;
https://*live*; will this cover all the sites with live in their path?